# ID of newly created entity not getting written into view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action that basically does this:

```
public ViewResult Save(Foo postedFoo)           
{
  Foo foo;
  if (postedFoo.Id == 0) //New foo; need to save for first time
  {
    foo = new Foo();
  }
  else //Already exists, need to load and update
  {
    foo = FooRepository.LoadFoo(postedFoo.Id);
  }
  UpdateModel(foo);
  FooRepository.Save(foo);
  return View(foo);
}
```

As you can see, the action handles both creating new `Foo` instances and updating existing ones.

The Foo's Id property is written into a hidden field in the view like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

The problem is that in the scenario where the user saves a new `Foo`, the `Foo`'s `Id` property (which is being set in the line `FooRepository.Save(foo)`) is NOT being written to the hidden field before the page is redisplayed to the user.

This means that if the user saves a new `Foo`, then immediately changes something and saves again, the controller thinks it's another new `Foo` and creates a new `Foo` in the database rather than just updating it.

Can anyone suggest why the hidden field is not being populated?

Comment: You should be using POST / REDIRECT / GET. Yes, there are other ways to solve this problem, but P / R / G is the *right* way.

Comment: Your two word question provides me with insufficient context to give any kind of useful answer.

Comment: lol. In what sense is it the right way? Or, to put it another way, in what sense is it a better solution than the one described?

Comment: POST / REDIRECT / GET is better for the usual reasons that P/R/G is good. Have you read about this? However, besides that point, it completely solves your problem with *no special code whatsoever* to make the ID thing work.

Comment: I have to admit that what I thought was quite a good pattern has been somewhat sullied by the need for 'special code' as you put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
ModelState.Remove("Id")
```

Before returning `View();`

This behavior is caused by the fact that `ModelState` is the primary supplier for values when rendering (yes, not the `Model` itself). So removing Id from `ModelState`, makes editors use `Model`'s value (In your case, updated `Id`)

Comment: Awesome. In my real code, the Id value is prefixed, so I needed to call `ModelState.Remove("myPrefix.Id")`. Your knowledge of MVC is awesome, archil.

Comment: I have to say, ModelState being the primary supplier is most counterintuitive.

Comment: It's only counterintuitive if you misuse it, which is what the code in the question does. It's perfectly reasonable if you consider the intended purpose of `ModelState`, which is re-displaying bad user input to the end user in the case where the save failed and the user is presented with their form again so that they can fix their bad input.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't the `else` line read

```
foo = FooRepository.LoadFoo(postedFoo.Id);
```

Also, the `new Foo();` isn't setting the value of `ID` anywhere unless you've hardcoded it into your model.
But if `FooRepository.Save(foo)` is meant to do this, it's not. You need to return the `ID` field back to your controller.

```
foo = FooRepository.Save(foo);
```

Comment: `new Foo()` will have an ID of 0 which is fine. Debugging confirms that `FooRepository.Save(foo)` is giving `foo` a new (positive) `Id` value. In the final line of the action (`return View(foo);`) debugging confirms that `foo.Id` has been set and is greater than zero.